# change button place in facebookfreebelvg magento 1.5

Tags: magento, facebook-graph-api

I installed the facebook connect from belvg in my store (filipeferminiano.com/lojateste) and I want to change the place of the facebook button. Where is the code that specifies these features? I already looked at the module's files but I didn't fint it.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can enable template path hints in developer menu to see the actual markup for facebook button.

Answer (score 0):

login button is located in `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/facebookfree/links.phtml`

```
<a href="#" onclick="return fblogin();" class="fb_button_ps"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('facebookfree/active')->getLoginImg()?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Connect with Facebook')?>" /></a>
```

Comment: I found this code, thanks. But my doubt it was how can i change the button of place (e.g. put it like a button in main menu)?